# Selecting a value from jQuery Chosen Dropdown using CodeCeption test script

Tags: testing, scripting, codeception, acceptance-testing

Hello i m trying to pick a value from jQuery Chosed Dropdown using codeception scripting, following is dev code

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-active" style="width: inherit;" title="" id="Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen">
<a tabindex="-1" class="chosen-single"><span>United States</span><div><b></b></div></a>
<div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div>
<ul class="chosen-results">
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Please select country</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">United States</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Canada</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">United Kingdom</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">Ireland</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">South Africa</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="6">Turkey</li></ul></div></div>                                    
<span class="note"><div style="display:none" id="Merchantserviceproviders_country_em_" class="errorMessage"></div></span></div>
```

Although i am able to select it using xpath via following;(United Stated in this case)

```
$I->click(['css' => 'div#Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen']);
$I->click(['xpath' => '//div[@id="Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen"]/div/ul/li[2]']);
```

But the issue is that the selection is through position of the value in the list, so as if any new value(country is added) i will not be able to select it until i know its placement.

I want to know how would i be able to select the country using its Value(United States in my case) not the placement in the list.

Comment: i elaborate more about my situation https://davidwalsh.name/demo/jquery-chosen.php can some one please follow the link and let me select 'Prototype' in the given dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have come up with following work around at the moment which seems to be a better option for me,,

```
$I->click(['css' => 'div#Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen']);
$I->fillField(['xpath' => '//div[@id="Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen"]/div/div/input'], 'United States'); 
$I->click(['xpath' => '//div[@id="Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen"]/div/ul/li[1]']);
```

In line 1, I click on the dropdown,, in line 2 i typed my desired country full name to narrow down the result(remember its a dropdown with search function),,, in line 3 i clicked on the 1st option after the searched result is shown on the drop down

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectOption` in this case.

```
$I->selectOption('dropdown-locator', 'option');
```

Example:

```
$I->selectOption('div#Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen', 'United States');
```

Comment: It not working,,,

 Step  I select option "div#Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen","United States"
 Fail  Radiobutton with value or name 'United States in element with 'div#Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen' was not found.

Comment: I just based the locator from your example. Make sure that the locator you used is valid.

Comment: the example you have given works fine on a general drop down but i have a 'chosen drop down' it is not working as u instructed